# What are the options to generate graphs from SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 database from which I need to build a daily automated report with graphs. What would be the best solution to create graph?

I was thinking about automating everything with C# and Excel, but I am hoping there would be an better/easier solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd humbly recommend a web and data framework my company writes (it's free, open source, and public domain) called [PowerShell Pipeworks](http://powershellpipeworks.com/).  This lets you graph with code like this:

```
Select-Sql -TableName DBTable | Out-Html -AsBarGraph
```

It also has a cmdlet, Start-At, to run things normally, so your  script would be something like

```
Start-At -Time "9:00 AM" -Everyday -ScriptBlock { 
    Select-Sql -TableName DBTable -ConnectionStringOrSetting SqlConnectionSecretSetting | Select-Object @{Name='DisplayedProperty';Expression={$_.CalculatedValue} | Out-Html -AsBarGraph |New-WebPage -UseJQueryUI | Set-Content $pathToHtmlFile
}
```

Comment: definitely recommend this company - I use their showui free tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can chart any sql query using [sqlchart](http://www.sqldashboards.com/sqlchart) from the command line. e.g. This generates a .png file 730x250:

```
sqlchart -D stockdb -P 1433 -servertype mssql -host localhost -e "select * from ohlc where sym='AMZN' AND (date > CURDATE()-60)" -o amazon-candlestick-dark.png --chart candlestick --height 250 --width 730 --theme dark
```

[image: sql stock chart]

Then you can attach that to an email using your standard scripting language. Instructions for emailing on linux are [here](http://www.sqldashboards.com/b/send-email-with-graphs/)

Answer (score 1):

Try Grafana. You can link it to an SQL database as well.
https://grafana.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get data from SQL using C# and then generate graph using library in [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) (I myself used EPPlus for the graph before). Both steps are very easy and standard.

Answer (score 0):

Install and design reports in SSRS - email/store them on a schedule.

Powershell is also an option, let me know if you need more details on powershell.

Comment: What about Powershell? SSRS is way too complex. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "batteries included" solution you can try [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), It can create reports from SQL Server, and other databases, and export or send them by email automatically with the Schedule Server option.

Answer (score 0):

Here are details on the powershell solution:

1. You will need to learn a little powershell ( you will never regret the time spent )
2. Install Powershell v3.0
3. Install module Invokesqlquery (this allows easy commuication to sql, can be downloaded from http://powershell4sql.codeplex.com/ )
4. Check out http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2009/04/28/3231887.aspx for charting